# How to add class-level custom method to angular rails resource

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ajax

I am using [angular-rails-resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) for the ajax calls from Angular 
and I want to create custom method in my resource which should behave in 
the same way as `.query()` method. Here is the code for the resource:

```js
 angular.module('mymodule').factory('Posts', ['railsResourceFactory',
   function(railsResourceFactory) {
     var resource = railsResourceFactory({
       url: 'api/v1/users/{{userId}}/posts',
       name: 'post'
     });

     resource.feed = function(userId, timestamp, page) {
       return resource.$get('api/v1/users/' + userId + '/posts/feed', {timestamp: timestamp, page: page});
     };

     return resource;
   }
 ]);
```

There are two problems with this code:

1. I have to define API route in two places in two different ways. I 
   would like to utilize resource url which is defined the first time.
2. I cannot call this like I would call `.query()` method since I have 
   userId as parameter directly, and not as an object.

How to improve this code to be more `.query()` method already defined in 
angular-rails-resource?
I would like to invoke this method `.feed()` in the following way:

```
Posts.feed({userId: $scope.userId}, {timestamp: new Date(), page:  1}).then(function success(posts){ /*...*/ }, function error() { /*...*/ });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is convenient method in angular rails resource called `.resourceUrl()` which accepts url parameters object and builds URL with it. You just have to change `.feed()` to look like this:

```
resource.feed = function(context, params) {
  return resource.$get(resource.resourceUrl(context) + '/feed', params);
};
```

So the complete service will have the following form:

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('Posts', ['railsResourceFactory',
  function (railsResourceFactory) {
    var resource = railsResourceFactory({
      url: 'api/v1/users/{{userId}}/posts',
      name: 'post'
    });

    resource.feed = function(context, params) {
      return resource.$get(resource.resourceUrl(context) + '/feed', params);
    };

    return resource;
  }
]);
```

Now you will be able to use `Posts.feed()` in the same way as you would've used `Posts.query()`.